# Could a process appear in top actually got stuck?

Tags: ps

Could a process appear in `top` actually got stuck?

Besides, I have read a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037632/how-to-see-if-a-process-is-suspended-in-unix) a command `ps -o s= -p <pid>` could show stopped process if the output is `T`.

I tried the command with various pid and have given me output `R` and `S`.

Any idea on what `T`, `R` and `S` mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man ps will give you more details:

```
           D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
           R    running or runnable (on run queue)
           S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
           T    stopped by job control signal
           t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
           W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
           X    dead (should never be seen)
           Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by
                its parent
```